# How to diagnose InnerException content on deployed (client machine) in unknown thread?

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a C# application running over Microsoft .NET (4.x), and on my 2 machines my application installs and run well.

On other machines (client machines), I can't debug : no visual studio, no symbol no debug mode.
But, they crash.
I have that in the windows event log:

```
例外情報:System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
スタック:
   場所 System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(System.RuntimeType, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean ByRef, System.RuntimeMethodHandleInternal ByRef, Boolean ByRef)
   場所 System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef)
   場所 System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef)
   場所 System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type, Boolean)
   場所 System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type)
   場所 DevExpress.XtraSplashScreen.ThreadManagerBase.CreateForm()
   場所 DevExpress.XtraSplashScreen.ThreadManagerBase.ThreadEntryPoint(System.Object)
   場所 System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
   場所 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   場所 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   場所 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   場所 System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(System.Object)
```

Normally, I have a crash interceptor that displays the call stack within the software itself, but it works only on the main thread.

Here my problem is, this thread looks like it is spawned by DevExpress (GUI framework) and I don't control this thread, and I can't code a crash catcher.
**I want to print out the "`InnerException`" content of the `TargetInvocationException` to see more details.**
How would you do that ?

Comment: How did you print out the exception you already have? Use the same technique on InnerException.

Comment: I am not sure in fact. I went to "asministration tools" in the windows control panel, and with the microsoft system log viewer, in the application "section", this call stack was visible. I don't know by what magic it ends up here. This log event is not something I can configure, and it is not dynamic (not like a debugger), so I can't expand fields from the class. Its just a printout.

Comment: You can use a dump analysis tool such as [DebugDiag](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42933) and set it to take a full dump once a `TargetInvocationException` occurs. Then, you can analyze the full stacktrace via the dump either from DebugDiag or by using `WinDBG`.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov perfect, this would be an accepted answer. thanks, I'll try it for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, [DebugDiag](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42933) is an excellent tool for production debugging.

You can set it to take a dump when a `TargetInvocationException` occurs. Later, you may also use it to diagnose the stacktrace, or if you need a more advanced tool, look into [WinDBG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=vs.85).aspx) with the managed [SOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764(v=vs.110).aspx) module.

Comment: It would be far better to add proper logging and an unhandled exception handler to log the error messages. There's no need to start debugging when you can view the entire exception in a file

Comment: @Panagiotis I agree, a full logging framework should be in order. I was assuming the OP needs this ASAP without the ability to deploy a newer version of the product. Adding a full-on logging framework to an existing app isn't always a quick fix.

Answer (score 1):

You should add logging to your application and log the entire exception yourself. Typically, calling `ToString()` prints the entire exception message, call stack and the inner exceptions as well. There are several logging libraries like log4net and NLog, so you don't have to create the logging infrastructure yourself.

Depending on your application type (WinForms, WPF, Web), you can add a handler to the appropriate unhandled exception event and log any uncaught exceptions there. Check these samples for [WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx), [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/processing-unhandled-exceptions-cs)

In WinForms you should set the exception handlers before creating the main form of the application:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Application.ThreadException += 
        new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(myThreadExceptionHandler);

    Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=
        new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(myUnhandledExceptionHandler);

    Application.Run(new MyStartForm());
}
```

while in WPF you need to catch the App's DispatcherUnhandledException event:

```
 public partial class App : Application
 {
        void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            //...
        }
 }
```

Comment: To my knowledge this would only work on the main thread. but maybe these libraries have some kind of crazy CLR access (or contract-type programming model?) that would wrap all threads at their creation time ?

Comment: ah your WinForms sample link about the `UnhandledException` is informative, I'll definitely try that out as well.

Comment: @v.oddou No, it works on all threads. No strange access needed, no wrapping or any special handling. The events are defined either at the application or the AppDomain level

Comment: actually I already have `ThreadException` plugged to a logger/crash sender report form. It just doesn't work in this case. Probably because either, the crashing thread is not a winform thread. Or devexpress manages to startup a thread before I plug the handler (which would be strange, I need to check). Anyway, the `UnhandledException` from the link seems like its capable to intercept any thread so I'll add this one too.